# Use Force Index with Hibernate JPA Repository Query Hint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Looking for a way to use Force Index on a MySQL query (not native).

Is it possible to create a custom QueryHint that can be registered and applied which will add the necessary sql `FORCE INDEX (some_index_name)` to the query?

If so can anyone give an example or point in the right direction for how to accomplish this.

Using MySQL 8, wanting to write a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Thing WHERE something = 1 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
```

I have the query working at the moment other than the index is not used the for update, skip locked etc is all sorted.

Tried a native query but it kept giving an error about some jpa mapping being null.
The query works fine other than it needs to force the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a custom Hibernate `Dialect` by providing a query comment. You can set the comment via a JPA query hint `org.hibernate.comment`. Then in the `Dialect` you can apply that comment by implementing `addSqlHintOrComment`.

Using SKIP LOCKED is easy though, you can write a query like this:

```
entityManager.createQuery("from Thing t where t.something = 1")
    .setMaxResults(1)
    .setHint("org.hibernate.lockMode", LockMode.UPGRADE_SKIPLOCKED)
```

Comment: Thanks @Christian, I attempted something like that but found that the hint was not applied because it was unrecognized there was a info log about it. I saw an abstract query contract that had some method forget the wording at the moment, but was not sure how I could make my own hint get applied as the hint is not present in the dialects hint query string function. Although was using at QueryHints

Comment: I'm telling you, this code works if the MySQL dialect supports skip locked. Update to the latest Hibernate version.